# Is it OK to decline a flag while accepting it in another way?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, rude-or-abusive

I recently raised a flag on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69578207/16936415) that was clearly rude to many people especially to the dedicated creators of the Go Language and many other Go developers.

Here is a snippet of the original question.

[image: Rude question]

I then raised a rude or abusive flag before any actions were taken (closed or edited). But then Undo declined my flag and said that the rude or abusive flag should only be used for moderator intervention. He then edited the question to make it less sensitive.

[image: Declined flag]

What could I have done in that situation? Which flag should I have raised?

This is a friendly discussion here—I don't want to spread hatred towards Undo because I like him anyway. I'm just kind of disappointed that my flag streak (100% helpful) is now ruined.

Comment: The R/A flag is for posts that should be quickly *deleted* (with a penalty to the author). This one could have been edited to remove the few offending parts.

Comment: I like Undo, too!

Comment: @JeanneDark Shouldn't this question be deleted beforehand? The question is clearly made up and doesn't seem to describe the exact problem the asker is facing.

Comment: We mods don't want you to flag posts as rude/abusive unless they are *irredeemably* so, and therefore need to be immediately deleted. In this case, it was just a bad choice of language in the code block, presumably out of frustration on the part of the author, rather than any true malice. That could be (and should have been) easily fixed with an edit, which can be submitted by anyone, without the need for moderator intervention. Thus, the flag was declined. I've changed your flag's status to "disputed", so it won't bring down your streak. You've learned what you were supposed to learn.

Comment: What you describe is maybe a close- and downvote-worthy question. But R/A flags are for posts that do not even attempt to contribute anything and are unsalvageable. An example would be a question/answer like "hgdjhcsdvjhsbvjhdsbvdsvbsv".

Comment: Also, @JeanneDark, something that is actually just inherently rude or abusive. Like an answer that says, "#^(& you, just read the $@%* docs you n00b". Or a question that is just a rant, not a question. (After taking a second look, this did seem pretty ranty, which makes me feel even better about changing that flag status to "disputed". But, we try to assume good faith, and when done liberally, I can see a programming question in there.)

Comment: @CodyGray I agree but the gibberish examples are easier and safer to post :)

Comment: I just enjoy the challenge of trying to find symbols that look like the intended letters. I don't think I succeeded very well this time.